# How to install a plugin in RAILS 5.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to install a plugin in RAILS. 
I tried something like this:

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git
```

but does not work.

Answer (score 5):

Rails 5 no longer supports plugins. This support was dropped in Rails 3.0

You should install Paperclip by using the [gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#installation)